# Changing Permissions with icacls

Tags: windows-10, permissions, nas, icacls

I recently started copying files to my local NAS where I ran into some minor problems. I am able to do everything I want over windows file explorer but it takes some time so I thought I may be using icacls.exe but I don’t know exactly how to. Maybe someone can help
Me, I‘ll explain where I need help.

First - Every file I copied says The permissions are incorrectly ordered and that I need to reorder them. So before I would change the permissions I’d need a command to do so for every file inside the directory.

After that I usually disable inheritance and convert the files to explicit permissions. How can I do that with icacls ?

And last but not least Lets say in one example directory there are 30 files. User A should get full access to all of them (can write, delete, read, etc.). User B should only get read and activate right to all of them but shouldn’t be able to write anything new or delete anything. And „everyone“ should only be able to read two files (for example file 1 and file 2). How do i set this via cmd ?

I hope someone can help me, would really appreciate it. Greetings.

Comment: What filesystem is the share?

Comment: The Filesystem on the NAS is ZFS but on windows it is NTFS (isn’t it?). It’s a SMB share

Comment: No, the filesystem of the zpool would be ZFS, not NTFS _(the share should have `streams_xattr, zfs_space, zfsacl` set)_. Are you using FreeNAS by chance?

Comment: Yes I’m using FreeNAS.

Comment: Are you running an up-to-date version, because if the share was properly created via the GUI as a Windows share, those ZFS values above should be set on the share - open the share's advanced properties in the FreeNAS GUI - what's listed for zfs objects/zfs attributes?

Comment: I only have ixnas and streams_cattle as VFS objects

Comment: You're definitely missing the correct objects for a Windows share, as neither of those are defaults for a Windows share and it's missing the default objects for a Windows share... Are you 100% this share was created as a Windows share in the GUI? You can also view the ZFS Objects types and definitions in the FreeNAS manual under Sharing > Windows (SMB). With ZFS, the share type and ZFS Objects matter for ACLs on Windows.

Comment: I am absolutely sure. It was set up with a ACL where I set the owner of the Share and also  set a basic permission for accessing it. Then with the Explorer I wanted to tweak the permissions. I'm on 11.3 if it matters.

Comment: You didn't configure a [Windows share](https://imgur.com/a/FzlBxCw) on FreeNAS if you set ownership/permissions on the share, as that's not possible with Windows shares via the GUI _(even if you used the menu next to the share and chose Edit ACL, that's for the pool's ACLs, not the share's)_ - a Windows share's ACLs are intended to be managed by Windows and Windows only, else problems can arise if not familiar with managing them via cli on FreeNAS ([VFS Objects](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.2/sharing.html#avail-vfs-modules-tab))